# Java integration with Microsoft Help

Tags: java, chm

I'm writing a GUI with Swing and I'm trying to integrate a microsoft chm help file. The problem is, I don't even know where to start. Can anyone recommend a library/tutorial as a starting point for a project like this? Specifically, I'd like to know about how to open/view specific pages or inidices (I don't even know exactly what the terminology for .chm files is) from java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually decided to go in a different direction for this project in particular (one that doesn't involve a MS help file), but here's a couple of helpful links I found in case anyone else runs into this issue:

[Wikipedia article on MS help format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compressed_HTML_Help)

[jchm](http://jchm.sourceforge.net/): a java library for using chm files. I didn't investigate it too thoroughly, but it's a starting point.